# Difference between template and view in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am new to CakePHP 3.0. Previously I used CodeIgniter. In CakePHP 3.0 we have to create our HTML designs in `src/Template` rather than `src/View`.

My question is what is the difference between a View and Template?

Answer (score 8):

Since 3.0 the folders containing view files now go under src/Template instead of src/View. This was done to separate the view files from files containing php classes (eg. Helpers, View classes).

so basicly your html (.ctp files) go into src/Template and your .php files 'helping' your templates go into src/View

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp uses the ctp extension. Stands for cake template. And for CRUD it uses add, view, edit, index ctp files.

In cakephp 2.0 the ctp (template files) are stored in app > View > ... folder.

In cakephp 3.0 the ctp files are stored in src > Template > ... or src > View > ... folder.

View:
Presentational classes are placed here: cells, helpers, and template files.

Template:
Presentational files are placed here: elements, error pages, layouts, and view template files.

Comment: Still i am not getting.If you want to create simple registration form.Where do you place the html part of that in view or template? and why?

Comment: I know its confusing but [this excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349464/difference-between-template-and-view-in-cake-php#:~:text=so%20basicly%20your%20html%20(.ctp%20files)%20go%20into%20src/Template%20and%20your%20.php%20files%20%27helping%27%20your%20templates%20go%20into%20src/View) from Alex Stallen answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

To src/Template, it is folder for view files.